# Getting NullPointerException while using onEjbCreate method of Deprecated AbstractStatelessSessionBean in Spring 3.2.6 with EJB 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an existing application developed using Spring 2.5, which I had to migrate to 3.2.6.
After the migration, everything is working fine.. except I'm getting a `NullPointerException` while using `onEjbCreate()` method of Deprecated `AbstractStatelessSessionBean` in Spring 3.2.6 .
I think the problem is that *onEjbCreate()* is not compatible with EJB 3.0.
I tried using `@PostConstruct` ,but then I was not able to get what to substitute for the existing `getBeanFactory()`.

Would appreciate if anyone can help me with this.
Thanks.

This is the existing code that was working on Spring 2.5

```
@Override
protected void onEjbCreate() throws CreateException {
    mqConnectorFactory = (ConnectorFactory) getBeanFactory().getBean(BEAN_NAME_MQ_CONN_FACTORY);
}
```

Comment: `AbstractStatelessSessionBean` isn't EJB3 it is EJB2 so it isn't going to work like that. See the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#ejb-implementation-ejb3) for EJB3 integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed `AbstractStatelessSessionBean` is `deprecated` in favor of EJB3 style implementation and in Spring 4.0 it is removed altogether.

For EJB3 the Spring provides [`SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html#ejb-implementation-ejb3)

Having that you can simply using this:

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class MyEjb {

   @Autowired
   private ConnectionFactory mqConnectorFactory;

}
```

Of course, you should be sure that you configure Spring correctly: `beanRefContext.xml` in the classpath.