# OC4J application to Weblogic 11g EJB error

Tags: spring, weblogic, ejb-3.0

I am trying to deploy an application that was originally developed for OC4J. It was compliled under JDK 1.5 and ran on OC4J R3.

I deployed it to Weblogic 11g (10.3.6) and got the following error:

Exception preparing module: EJBModule(XXX-ejb-1.0.jar) Unable to deploy EJB: XXX-ejb-1.0.jar from XXX-ejb-1.0.jar: In EJB XXXXXXXXXX, both the remote home and remote component interface must be specified. Currently, only one of them is specified. 
 Substituted for missing class In EJB XXXXXXXXX, both the remote home and remote component interface must be specified. Currently, only one of them is specified. -

It is referring to an EJB 3.0 as defined in the ejb-jar.xml ejb-jar version="3.0" and afaik this seems to be an EJB 2.1 error because EJB 3 doesn't require both remote and home interfaces. The EJB is a Stateless Session bean that uses Spring 2.5.6 DI and doesn't use annotations, rather the ejb-jar.xml deployment descriptor.

```
 public class myEJBImpl extends AbstractStatelessSessionBean
    implements myEJB {


@Override
// Use Spring DI
protected void onEjbCreate() throws CreateException {

    xxxDAO = xxx;

}
```

Comment: And how is this related to EJB3 as you aer using a EJB2.x. The `AbstractStatelessSessionBean` is a EJB2 not EJB3.

Comment: I am just trying to get existing code that worked in OC4J to get to work on weblogic. I didn't write the code myself. So you are saying that AbstractStatelessSessionBean should be removed to be EJB3 compliant?

Comment: It is deprecated in version 3: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ejb/support/AbstractStatelessSessionBean.html So a good starting place would be refactoring some of that code, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22804418/getting-nullpointerexception-while-using-onejbcreate-method-of-deprecated-abstra

Comment: Thanks for the replies. So this AbstractStatelessSessionBean won't work in EJB 3.0 but that begs the question, why and how did this work in the old container OC4J? Maybe the error was ignored and is now picked upby weblogic

Comment: Hmmm I removed AbstractStatelessSessionBean and added the Autowired to the xxxDAO. I still get the exact same error message, it's treating it as an EJb2.1 instead of EJB3. I even added @Stateless annotation to the class, even though that's in the ejb-jar-xml and is redundant, but doesn't help

Comment: Now I'm just removing the ejb-jar.xml. Even though EJB3 allows you to use it (so that you can easily migrate from 2.1 to 3, ) weblogic treats it as an EJB it seems. And OC4J handled it just fine. I'll have to convert the ejb-jar.xml descriptor to annotations I am thinking (as well as deal with that abstractstatelesssessionbean)